# Difference between @RemoteAction annotation and <apex:actionFunction>?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can someone tell me the difference between these VF tags... in brief?

Answer (score 36):

`@RemoteAction` and `apex:actionFunction` are essentially polar opposites in terms of functionality, even though they both offer JavaScript functionality.

`@RemoteAction` methods are static, and therefore can't see the current page state directly, while `apex:actionFunction` methods are instance methods, and so can see the entire page state.

`@RemoteAction` methods require less bandwidth, and server processing time, because only the data you submit is visible and the view state is not transferred, while `apex:actionFunction` has to transfer the page view state.

`@RemoteAction` methods have to update the DOM manually using explicit JavaScript, while `apex:actionFunction` methods automatically update the Visualforce DOM and can refresh part or all of the page, and can provide a standard interface for showing a loading status through `apex:actionStatus`.

`@RemoteAction` methods can return data directly back to the calling JavaScript, but cannot update the page's view state. `apex:actionFunction` methods can update the page's view state and DOM structure, but cannot return data directly back to JavaScript (although you can do this with some extra effort using `oncomplete`).

Because of these polar differences, there is almost always "one right answer" for which method should be used in a given situation. An auto-complete-as-you-type feature would benefit from `@RemoteAction`, because less data is used, and so it is faster and more responsive; we don't need to modify the view state, so this is a major bonus for the user. Updating the page's view state to show new Visualforce elements, in contrast, would best be served with `apex:actionFunction`; using a `@RemoteAction` would force the developer to manage the DOM themselves, which can be more burdensome.

Also, you generally can't modify the DOM in native JavaScript if you use `apex:actionFunction`, because those changes won't appear in the view state and will be overwritten if the DOM node the changes appeared in is refreshed. This means that JavaScript designed to use `@RemoteAction` and update the DOM as a result will generally be incompatible with `apex:actionFunction`. There's exceptions to this rule, of course, as long as both uses are isolated from each other or interact only in a carefully designed order of operations.

Comment: An `apex:actionFunction` can rerender a script tag containing merge fields which will be reflected in the view state and can be used to update the DOM.

Comment: Thnaks mate..very helpful..!!!

Answer (score 13):

`@RemoteAction` is an Apex annotation used to mark a method as being available for javascript remoting. This allows you to call the method from javascript yourself and retrieve the result as a javascript object for manipulation, [as per the example in the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm). They are static and global, and hence don't have access to your current controller variables and methods.

`<apex:actionFunction>` is a Visualforce tag which has been around longer than remoting and allows you to invoke a controller action from javascript; it doesn't let you get retrieve data but you can rerender the page or a specific section of the page to update it with new values from the controller instance.

Answer (score -2):

The difference between these two is briefed at very bottom of this [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm)