# Why actionFunctions are not as fast as RemoteAction

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, remote-action, apexactionfunction

Can anyone tell me why actionFunctions are not as fast as RemoteActions in Vf pages?

Answer (score 4):

In the [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17375/difference-between-remoteaction-annotation-and-apexactionfunction) @sfdcfox have provided several good points.Posting some of them which are related to your answer:

1. `@RemoteAction` methods require less bandwidth, and server processing time, because only the data you submit is visible and the view state is not transferred, while `apex:actionFunction` has to transfer the page view state.
2. There is almost always "one right answer" for which method should be used in a given situation. An auto-complete-as-you-type feature would benefit from `@RemoteAction`, because less data is used, and so it is faster and more responsive; we don't need to modify the view state, so this is a major bonus for the user. Updating the page's view state to show new Visualforce elements, in contrast, would best be served with `apex:actionFunction;` using a `@RemoteAction` would force the developer to manage the DOM themselves, which can be more burdensome.