# Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded" error message in vf page

Tags: apex, viewstate

I have the following code and i am just getting the following error, How can i reduce the size of view state ?

[image]

> Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded" error message

```
    public class MyPagingController
{
    private List<Quote> quotes;
    private List<Quote> pageQuotes;
    private String sortDirection = 'DESC';
    private String sortExp = 'createdDate';
    private Integer pageNumber;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer totalPageNumber;
    public String searchQuoteName { get; set; }
    public String searchQuoteNumber { get; set; }

    public Integer getPageNumber()
    {
        return pageNumber;
    }

    public String sortExpression
    {
        get 
        {
            return sortExp;
        } 
        set
        {
            if (value == sortExp)
                sortDirection = (sortDirection == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            else
                sortDirection = 'ASC';
            sortExp = value;
        }
    }
    public String getSortDirection()
    {
        if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '')
            return 'ASC';
        else
            return sortDirection;
    }

    public void setSortDirection(String value)
    {  
        sortDirection = value;
    }

    public List<Quote> getQuotes()
    {
        return pageQuotes;
    }
    public Integer getPageSize()
    {
        return pageSize;
    }
    public Boolean getPreviousButtonEnabled()
    {
        return !(pageNumber > 1);
    }
    public Boolean getNextButtonDisabled()
    {
        if (quotes == null) return true;
        else
        return ((pageNumber * pageSize) >= quotes.size());
    }

    public Integer getTotalPageNumber()
    {
        if (totalPageNumber == 0 && quotes !=null)
        {
            totalPageNumber = quotes.size() / pageSize;
            Integer mod = quotes.size() - (totalPageNumber * pageSize);
            if (mod > 0)
                totalPageNumber++;
            }
        return totalPageNumber;
    }
    public MyPagingController()
    {
        pageNumber = 0;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        pageSize = 20;
        ViewData();
    }

    public PageReference ViewData()
    {
        quotes = null;
        totalPageNumber = 0;        
        BindData(1);        
        return null;
    }

    private void BindData(Integer newPageIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            string sortFullExp = sortExpression  + ' ' + sortDirection;

            string searchQuoteName = searchQuoteName;
            system.debug('searchQuoteName ==== '+searchQuoteName);

            String searchQuery = '';
            String s = '';
            String squote = '';

            if(searchQuoteName != null){
                s = '\'%' + searchQuoteName + '%\''; 
                searchQuery = ' WHERE Name LIKE '+s; 
            }

            if(searchQuery != ''){
                if(searchQuoteNumber != null){
                    squote = '\'%' + searchQuoteNumber + '%\''; 
                    searchQuery += ' AND QuoteNumber LIKE '+squote; 
                }    
            }else{
                if(searchQuoteNumber != null){
                    squote = '\'%' + searchQuoteNumber + '%\''; 
                    searchQuery = ' WHERE QuoteNumber LIKE '+squote; 
                }
            }

            system.debug('searchquery ===='+searchQuery);

            if (quotes == null)                
                system.debug('Select Id, Name, Opportunity.Name, QuoteNumber, TotalPrice, CreatedDate, GrandTotal from Quote '+searchQuery +' order by ' +sortFullExp);
                quotes = Database.query('Select Id, Name, Opportunity.Name, QuoteNumber, TotalPrice, CreatedDate, GrandTotal, CreatedById, LastModifiedById from Quote '+searchQuery +' order by ' +sortFullExp+ ' Limit 10000');
                pageQuotes = new List<Quote>{};
                Transient Integer counter = 0;
                Transient Integer min = 0;
                Transient Integer max = 0;
                if (newPageIndex > pageNumber)
                {
                    min = pageNumber * pageSize;
                    max = newPageIndex * pageSize;
                }
                else
                {
                    max = newPageIndex * pageSize;
                    min = max - pageSize;
                }

                for(Quote a : quotes)
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > min && counter <= max)
                        pageQuotes.add(a);
                }
                pageNumber = newPageIndex;
                if (pageQuotes == null || pageQuotes.size() <= 0)
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Data not available for this view.'));
                }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public PageReference nextBtnClick() {
        BindData(pageNumber + 1);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference previousBtnClick() {
        BindData(pageNumber - 1);
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference Search() {
        //BindData(pageNumber);
        BindData(1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quotes}" var="c" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(quotes))}" rows="{!PageSize}">

     <apex:column width="15%">
       <apex:facet name="header">   
         <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Quote Name{!IF(sortExpression=='name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort">
           <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
         </apex:commandLink>
       </apex:facet>
       <apex:outputlink value="/apex/QuoteDetail?id={!c.Id}">{!c.name}</apex:outputlink>
     </apex:column>

      <apex:column width="35%" headerValue="Opportunity Name">
        <apex:outputlink value="/{!c.OpportunityId}" target="_blank">{!c.Opportunity.Name}</apex:outputlink>
     </apex:column>

     <apex:column width="10%" value="{!c.QuoteNumber}">
       <apex:facet name="header">   
         <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Quote Number{!IF(sortExpression=='QuoteNumber',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdNumberSort">
           <apex:param value="QuoteNumber" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
         </apex:commandLink>
       </apex:facet>
     </apex:column>

      <apex:column width="10%" headerValue="Quote Amount" value="{!c.GrandTotal}"/>

      <apex:column width="15%" value="{!c.createdDate}">
       <apex:facet name="header">   
         <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Date{!IF(sortExpression=='createdDate',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdCreatedAtSort">
           <apex:param value="createdDate" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
         </apex:commandLink>
       </apex:facet>
     </apex:column>

      <apex:column width="35%" headerValue="Created By">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.createdById}"/>
          <!--<apex:outputField value="{!c.createdDate}"/>-->
      </apex:column>

      <apex:column width="35%" headerValue="Modified By">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.LastModifiedById}"/>
          <!--<apex:outputField value="{!c.LastModifiedDate}"/>-->
      </apex:column>

      <apex:column width="8%" headerValue="View">
        <apex:outputlink style="color:blue;" value="/apex/QuoteDetail?id={!c.Id}">View Detail</apex:outputLink>
      </apex:column>

      <apex:column width="5%" headerValue="Edit">
        <apex:outputlink style="color:blue;" value="/apex/QuoteGroupCreate?id={!c.Id}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
      </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Short answer is - use pagination and make container of total quotes as `transient`. It this case all quotes would not be in view state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work through your code and see which ones can be marked as **transient**. This will exclude them from view state.

```
 private transient  List<Quote> pageQuotes;
```

Below is the full working code of your page  Re-modified. few Changes i have did both on your visual page and controller. I guess no need more explanation your code.

**VisualPage :**

```
<apex:page controller="MyPagingController" tabStyle="Quote"> 
    <apex:sectionHeader title="List of Quotes"></apex:sectionHeader> 
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Quote"> 
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:Bold;" value="Quote Name : " /> 
            <apex:inputText value="{!searchQuoteName}" /> 

            <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:Bold;" value="Quote Number : " /> 
            <apex:inputText value="{!searchQuoteNumber}" /> 
            <br/><br/> 

            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Search}" reRender="pageBlock"></apex:commandButton> 
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form> 
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock title="List of Quotes" id="pageBlock"> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" dir="LTR" > 
                <apex:commandButton value="Create New Quote" action="/apex/QuoteGroupCreate?editmode=False" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 


            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quotes}" var="c" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(quotes))}" rows="{!PageSize}"> 

                <apex:column width="15%"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header"> 
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Quote Name{!IF(sortExpression=='name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort"> 
                            <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param> 
                        </apex:commandLink> 
                    </apex:facet> 
                    <apex:outputlink value="/apex/QuoteDetail?id={!c.Id}">{!c.name}</apex:outputlink> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="35%" headerValue="Opportunity Name"> 
                    <apex:outputlink value="/{!c.OpportunityId}" target="_blank">{!c.Opportunity.Name}</apex:outputlink> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="10%" value="{!c.QuoteNumber}"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header"> 
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Quote Number{!IF(sortExpression=='QuoteNumber',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdNumberSort"> 
                            <apex:param value="QuoteNumber" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param> 
                        </apex:commandLink> 
                    </apex:facet> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="10%" headerValue="Quote Amount" value="{!c.GrandTotal}"/> 

                <apex:column width="15%" value="{!c.createdDate}"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header"> 
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Date{!IF(sortExpression=='createdDate',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdCreatedAtSort"> 
                            <apex:param value="createdDate" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param> 
                        </apex:commandLink> 
                    </apex:facet> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="35%" headerValue="Created By"> 
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.createdById}"/> 
                    <!--<apex:outputField value="{!c.createdDate}"/>--> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="35%" headerValue="Modified By"> 
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.LastModifiedById}"/> 
                    <!--<apex:outputField value="{!c.LastModifiedDate}"/>--> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="8%" headerValue="View"> 
                    <apex:outputlink style="color:blue;" value="/apex/QuoteDetail?id={!c.Id}">View Detail</apex:outputLink> 
                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column width="5%" headerValue="Edit"> 
                    <apex:outputlink style="color:blue;" value="/apex/QuoteGroupCreate?id={!c.Id}">Edit</apex:outputLink> 
                </apex:column> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            <div align="right" style="display:{!IF(quotes.size > 0,'block','none')}"> 
                <br/> 
                <font size="1pt">Page #:&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!PageNumber}"/>&nbsp;out of&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!totalPageNumber}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" disabled="{! NOT(hasPrevious)}" reRender="pageBlock" ></apex:commandButton> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" reRender="pageBlock" disabled="{! NOT(hasNext)}" ></apex:commandButton> 
            </div> 
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
public class MyPagingController{
    public transient List<Quote> quotes{get;private set;}

    private String sortDirection = 'DESC';
    private String sortExp = 'createdDate';
    public final decimal pageSize {get;set;} // Modified by Nail David because pageSize is unknown property for visualforce page
    public Integer totalPageNumber{get;private set;}
    public String searchQuoteName { get; set; }
    public String searchQuoteNumber { get; set; }

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon{get;set;}

    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return setCon.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return setCon.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return setCon.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }


    public void previous() {
        setCon.previous();
        quotes= (List<quote>)setCon.getRecords();    
    }

    public void next() {
        setCon.next();
        quotes= (List<quote>)setCon.getRecords();        
    }

    public String sortExpression    {
        get 
        {
            return sortExp;
        } 
        set
        {
            if (value == sortExp)
                sortDirection = (sortDirection == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            else
                sortDirection = 'ASC';
            sortExp = value;
        }
    }

    public String getSortDirection()    {
        if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '')
            return 'ASC';
        else
            return sortDirection;
    }

    public void setSortDirection(String value)    {  
        sortDirection = value;
    }

    public MyPagingController()  {
        pageSize = 20; // Added by Nail David
        string queryString = 'Select Id, Name, Opportunity.Name, QuoteNumber, TotalPrice, CreatedDate, GrandTotal, CreatedById, LastModifiedById from Quote';
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
        setCon.setPageSize((Integer)pageSize);
        quotes= (List<quote>)setCon.getRecords();    
        totalPageNumber=(Integer)  (setCon.getResultSize()/pageSize).round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
    }

    public PageReference ViewData()
    {   
        BindData();        
        return null;
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
            string sortFullExp = sortExpression  + ' ' + sortDirection;            
            string searchQuoteName = searchQuoteName;
            String searchQuery = '';
            String s = '';
            String squote = '';

            if(searchQuoteName != null){
                s = '\'%' + searchQuoteName + '%\''; 
                searchQuery = ' WHERE Name LIKE '+s; 
            }

            if(searchQuery != ''){
                if(searchQuoteNumber != null){
                    squote = '\'%' + searchQuoteNumber + '%\''; 
                    searchQuery += ' AND QuoteNumber LIKE '+squote; 
                }    
            }else{
                if(searchQuoteNumber != null){
                    squote = '\'%' + searchQuoteNumber + '%\''; 
                    searchQuery = ' WHERE QuoteNumber LIKE '+squote; 
                }
            }

        string queryString = 'Select Id, Name, Opportunity.Name, QuoteNumber, TotalPrice, CreatedDate, GrandTotal, CreatedById, LastModifiedById from Quote '+searchQuery +' order by ' +sortFullExp+ ' Limit 10000';
        System.debug('query *******' + queryString);
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));       
        setCon.setPageSize((Integer)pageSize);
        quotes= (List<quote>)setCon.getRecords();        
        totalPageNumber=(Integer)  (setCon.getResultSize()/pageSize).round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
    }

    public PageReference Search() {
        BindData();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: quotes to send to view page should have `public` getter and shouldn't be transient.

Comment: @NITHESHK but it still show me same size limit, is that correct ?

Comment: @NailDavid can you post me both vf code also . so i can understand which one is need in vf page

Comment: @NITHESHK updated my question and added vf page's pageblock table

Comment: @NailDavid You wanted to do search pagination over a Quotes right ?

Comment: @NITHESHK yes right !!

Comment: You can simple do with the help standard controller . let give me a time i will restructure code for you.

Comment: I just want tell you something that i have update this line and size reduces itself but then pagination does not work. `private transient List<Quote> quotes;`

Comment: @NailDavid yes sure , let me help you .

Comment: @NailDavid ViewData() function is missing in your controller ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65281/discussion-between-nail-david-and-nithesh-k).

Comment: @NailDavid I had posted answer in discussion early, i guess you have not received  it, So i updated answer here itself.  Let me know if have any question .

Comment: @NITHESHK Thanks for this and i have made little change in apex class (see comments) in the code that i have edited. :)

Comment: @NailDavid OKay sure. Its your basic needs , You can change how u needed .

Comment: @NailDavid One more Suggestion your working larger data-set its always better to use remote-action , Its always faster compare  to  using any command-button or action-function etc..

Comment: No. i did not get you. can you please explain me in some other words ?

Comment: i Hope this will help u more  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000ADFwIAO  ,  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17375/difference-between-remoteaction-annotation-and-apexactionfunction

Comment: @NailDavid Your welcome..

Comment: @NITHESHK I am not sure but Sorting is not working for this code. can you help me with above code ??...it was working with very first code i shared.

Comment: @NailDavid Can you post your Orignal code with different question , where and what problem your facing ?

Comment: @NailDavid how you wanted sorted your record? Which basic ?

Comment: @NITHESHK New question might be getting duplicate question tag :) Sorted record by date ASC & DSC. i have just used your code, i have not updated anything in your code. can you please check ?

Comment: @NailDavid I can't post answer here , its already marked as duplicate.   Ask a question saying problem with sorting Quote

Comment: @NITHESHK I have posted [this question for sorting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192371/problem-with-sorting-quote) please have a look and let me know what i did wrong in that code. many thanks :)